# document.form_name.elements undefined in ie

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm getting an undefined error in IE11 when I try to execute the following Javascript: `alert('obj: ' + document.payment_method.elements['285_id[35]']);`

Non array notation form names seem to work fine. Here some test in js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o2d2c16r/2/

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
<form name="payment_method">
    <select name="285_id[35]">
        <option value="1">value 1</option>
        <option value="2">value 2</option>
        <option value="3">value 3</option>
        <option value="4">value 4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="mytext" value="text entered" />
    <select name="myselect">
        <option value="a">value a</option>
        <option value="b">value b</option>
        <option value="c">value c</option>
        <option value="d">value d</option>
    </select>
</form>

    <script>
alert('obj: ' + document.payment_method.elements['285_id[35]']);
alert('obj: ' + document.payment_method.elements['mytext']);
alert('obj: ' + document.payment_method.elements['myselect']);
alert('obj length: ' + document.payment_method.elements['myselect'].length);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks,

Gunter

Comment: Running your code in IE11 gives me a script error "Object doesn't support property of method 'querySelector'".